# my https website can't download by WGET command

Tags: https, wget

I can browse the page by browser, but I can't download the html page by wget.
https://money.benck.tw

When I use wget, it can't even connect to the website:

```
--2011-10-12 05:30:24--  https://money.benck.tw/
Resolving money.benck.tw... 97.107.135.68
Connecting to money.benck.tw|97.107.135.68|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2011-10-12 05:33:35--  (try: 2)  https://money.benck.tw/
Connecting to money.benck.tw|97.107.135.68|:443...
```

However, I can download the other https website like: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js
It's very weird.

Comment: What exactly is the error and what wget syntax are you trying??

Comment: The error is just like what I post, the command I typed is: "wget https: //money.benck.tw" (I put a space in case it will become a link on the page)

Comment: I found the answer. It's blocked by iptables but I don't know why...

Comment: It's not iptables that's blocking it, it's the fact that it's utilizing HTTPS and wget is unable to locally verify the issuer's authority. It cannot establish an SSL connection so you need to use the --no-check-certificate command. See my answer below.

Comment: It is because of iptables. Using wget on the same machine results in using loopback network interface. After accept all lo, it's fine now.

Answer (score 2):

For this website you have to use the --no-check-certificate command

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://money.benck.tw
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiments the same issue, I trying to download files from an external site like https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/easy-wp-smtp.zip and I wget using --no-check-certificate stills not working.... It's freezing in this line:

Connecting to downloads.wordpress.org (downloads.wordpress.org)|198.143.164.250|:443...

Anyone have the same issue?

No IP tables configured and rules. When I do this on other server on the same networks works fine. This only happens on this server specialy.

Regards,
Francisco Yu

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please refrain from asking questions in another question's answer. I understand you cannot comment due to your rep so it might be best to rephrase your question and ask it in a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of this page is probably scraped by `wget` too often. You need to modify headers, especially useragent.

Examples from other website:

--no-check-certificate does not hepls

```
 wget --no-check-certificate "https://www.money.pl/pieniadze/depozyty/walutowearch/1921-02-05,2021-02-05,LIBORCHF3M,strona,1.html"                                                                  --2021-02-05 17:05:34--  https://www.money.pl/pieniadze/depozyty/walutowearch/1921-02-05,2021-02-05,LIBORCHF3M,strona,1.html
Loaded CA certificate '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'
Resolving www.money.pl (www.money.pl)... 212.77.101.20
Connecting to www.money.pl (www.money.pl)|212.77.101.20|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2021-02-05 17:05:34 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

but other tool to download sendign other headers works

```
 http -h "https://www.money.pl/pieniadze/depozyty/walutowearch/1921-02-05,2021-02-05,LIBORCHF3M,strona,1.html"  
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-control: max-age=60, public,stale-while-revalidate=5
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 20756
Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests;
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-2
Date: Fri, 05 Feb 2021 16:04:16 GMT
Link: <https://money.wp.pl/dGxwOTV0SyYZFTlneUtGM1pNbSY9EkhlJ1V1dglvOxgnKBALCW87GCcoEAsJbzsYJygQCwlvOxgnKBALCW87GCcoEAsJbzsYJygQCwlvOxgnKBALCW87GCcoEAsJbzsYJygQCwlvOxgnKBALCW87GCcoEAsJbzsYJygQCwlvOxgnKBALCW87GCcobXh0RUZ9WlgoNTAeDjRHBTlpZxYWIhMeKydrAld1TER2ciZYECoUSjgjIR4JKBYSNnomXEF1TUUJJD9VCi4ZEzUxcwJRdT4TKiQ5Sh0zAVJ9YWR2EyYUAjs7IVUFNRsfamZjAiJ2QUV-eWYCSXdNUn1hZHNWd0pGYmRkHVRyXUV6ZhV8LQU3JQwcEAMpYkpCfRclRBYoFhZqZmMCJ3ZWHzs5OhY0EDkoLjA0VFl1XgQ_PTgNKRMbQgIuB0lCIRQEOzUiWQB6XhYrIgVcCzMLSn9lZhYHJBkDKjM5Qh16DxYjISJJRjo=>;rel="preload";as="script";
Server: nginx
Set-Cookie: mny_ver2=v8c;Domain=.money.pl;Path=/;Max-Age=2592000;
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```